# How to run multiple soapui OSS project with maven-soapui-extension-plugin?

Tags: maven, soapui

when i run the plugin maven-soapui-extension-plugin to execute multiples project, i have Build successfull but nothing has run. Could you help me please ?

I have runned this command : mvn com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui:maven-soapui-extension-plugin:test-multi -X > cmd.log

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/474569/cmd.log

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>soapui-multi-projects</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-multi</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <runnerType>OSS</runnerType>
                        <projectFiles>
                            <scan>
                                <baseDirectory>${basedir}/test/suite/soapui/suites/</baseDirectory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <!-- <excludes> <exclude>**/*fail-*-soapui-project.xml</exclude> 
                                    </excludes> -->
                            </scan>
                        </projectFiles>
                        <outputFolder>${basedir}/build/soapui-reports/</outputFolder>
                        <useOutputFolderPerProject>true</useOutputFolderPerProject>
                        <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                        <junitHtmlReport>false</junitHtmlReport>
                        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                    <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
                    <version>4.6.4</version>
                    <exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this maven command : mvn integration-test com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui:maven-soapui-extension-plugin:4.6.4.2:test-multi